# tsconfig.json gets reset after yarn start React app

Tags: typescript

I created my React app with `create-react-app app_name --typescript`. Since Typescript doesn't support NODE_PATH. I'm trying to use baseUrl in `tsconfig.json`.

However, every time running `yarn start` after putting `"baseUrl": "src"` in `"compilerOptions"`, the baseUrl gets gone. I feel like `yarn start` resets `tsconfig.json`.

How can I stop it to reset the file?

```
**tsconfig.json**
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

Comment: Check this out. It's working for me https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5645#issuecomment-461999138

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53794875/how-to-configure-react-script-so-that-it-doesnt-override-tsconfig-json-on-star

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53438548/tsconfig-json-gets-reset-after-yarn-start-react-app

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's a workaround.

1. Create a new file, say "base-tsconfig.json" and put the baseUrl config and paths in there. Those won't be overwritten by CRA.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

2. Extend the main tsconfig.json file with your custom configuration

```
{
  "extends": "./base-tsconfig.json"
}
```

More info [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5645).

Answer (score 3):

create-react-app currently removes the `baseUrl` property, I don't think paths are currently supported by them unfortunately :(

Read more here https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5585

Comment: To anyone who reads this solution, this is no longer true, please refer to this github pull request: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/6656 which enabled set baseUrel from tsconfig/jsconfig

Answer (score 2):

baseUrl **issue is fixed in create-react-app 3**. It now supports two values - `node_modules`(the default) and `src` (refer this [comment](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5692#issuecomment-485891399))

Upgrade create-react-app using instructions in [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).

*Eg:* if you want to upgrade from 2.1.x to 3.0.0,

```
npm install --save --save-exact react-scripts@3.0.0
```

or

```
yarn add --exact react-scripts@3.0.0
```

*Note:* I used to have both `jsconfig.json` and `tsconfig.json`, but it threw an error in the beginning. Removing `jsconfig.json` resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

**Path aliases are not supported anymore**

But you can do this now to directly import files relative to the `src` directory

go to your `tsconfig.json` file add `baseUrl` to be `"."`

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl":".",
    ...
```

Then you will be able to directly import stuff relative to the `src` directory

```
import Myfile from "src/myfile.js"
```

**This worked for me!**