# Creating custom absolute paths with create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app, tsconfig-paths

I've created a React project with typescript using `create-react-app` version `3.4.1`.
I'm trying to avoid the use of relative paths in my project. Here's a part of my project tree:

```
/
|_ public
|_ tests
|_ src
  |____ Scenarios
  |____ Components
        |____c
```

What I basically want is to be able to to do something like `import '@components/c'`. I've tried to add this part to my `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{

"compilerOptions": {
...
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["src/*"],
      "tests": ["tests/*"],
      "public": ["public/*"],
      "@components/*": ["src/Components/*"],
      "@Scenarios/*": ["src/Scenarios/*"],
      },
...
   }
}
```

But every time I'm starting my app using `yarn start` my tsconfig deletes this part of my code (eveything but my "baseUrl" part). [As far as I know](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/6656) since version 3 of `react-create-app`, solved this problem **partially** with enabling `baseUrl` property to affect the imports' root dir. But I couldn't find anywhere a working solution to set absolute paths from tsconfig `path` directory. The partial solution doesn't work for me as I'm probably going to import stuff from public directory.

**I did try this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59070521/4026227) from last year but it wouldn't work for me.** Did anyone manage to get this or any other solution working?

Ideally the solution will enable me to still use create-react-app and not to use other packages but of course any solution would work.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with your solution by add tsconfig.extends.json and use craco or any library to custom webpack. This is my craco.config.js:

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  webpack: {
    alias: {
      src: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/')
    }
  }
}
```